# iPhone OSC Library

Tags: iphone, osc

I know there are some iPhone Apps out there that use OSC and i'm wondering now if someone of them released a nice library for it. I googled a loot around but didn't found anything. Maybe someone knows how to google better then me :)

I'm currently trying to get OSCKit to work on the iPhone, but i'm not that good in iPhone development.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The one i'm using now is the ios build of vvosc from here: https://github.com/brennon/vvocs-frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSC-Kit was replaced by WOscLib

-t

Comment: hi i would like to send strings from my iphone to the application on the mac via wifi local network everytime the user slides a UISlider on my application on the iphone it needs to send strings with values on it to notify the application on my mac straight away so it can print it. What should i use? because bonjour isnt that great for a live connection.

Answer (score 3):

TouchOSC is using [oscpack](http://www.audiomulch.com/~rossb/code/oscpack/)

It's implemented in C++ which might be awkward to use in an iPhone (I personally don't mind)

There's a pure Objective-C OSC framework called "VVOSC" which is easy to configure and use in an iPhone SDK context:
[vvopensource](http://code.google.com/p/vvopensource/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [dsmi](http://code.google.com/p/dsmi/)

Don't be put off by that "DS", it works on the iPhone too.

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer. But it looks like this library can only send osc messages. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: hi i would like to send strings from my iphone to the application on the mac via wifi local network everytime the user slides a UISlider on my application on the iphone it needs to send strings with values on it to notify the application on my mac straight away so it can print it. What should i use? because bonjour isnt that great for a live connection.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using PhoneGap, I implemented OSC for javascript (client-side) in my [KievII](http://kievii.net/index.html) library. Here's the [code](https://github.com/janesconference/KievII/blob/master/comm/osc.js).